# How can I make this code shorter on excel?

Tags: excel

is it possible to make this code shorter and simpler in excel 2010.

```
=A1&B1&C1&D1&A2&B2&C2&D2&A3&B3&C3&D3&A4&B4&C4&D4&A5&B5&C5&D5&A6&B6&C6&D6&A7&B7&C7&D7
```

if you could tell me a possible way to shorten this I would be grateful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a UDF like MultiCat:

```
  'Purpose: Concatenate all cells in a range
  'Inputs:  rRng - range to be concatenated
  '         sDelimiter - optional delimiter
  '            to insert between cell Texts
  'Returns: concatenated string
  '*****************************************
  Public Function MultiCat( _
        ByRef rRng As Excel.Range, _
        Optional ByVal sDelim As String = "") _
             As String
     Dim rCell As Range
     For Each rCell In rRng
        If rCell.Value <> "" Then
         MultiCat = MultiCat & sDelim & rCell.Text
         End If
     Next rCell
     MultiCat = Mid(MultiCat, Len(sDelim) + 1)
  End Function
```

Comment: Yours performs 50% faster than Gary's. Though he has a new one :) haven't tried it yet... http://superuser.com/a/1043623

Answer (score 1):

In a standard module, enter the following User Defined Function:

```
Public Function KonKat(Rin As Range) As String
    Dim r As Range
    For Each r In Rin
        KonKat = KonKat & r.Value
    Next r
End Function
```

User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the UDF from Excel:

```
=KonKat(A1:D7)
```

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

for specifics on UDFs

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Answer (score 0):

If you want a non macro/script option then...

=CONCATENATE(A1,B1,C1,D1,A2,B2,C2,D2,A3,B3,C3,D3,A4,B4,C4,D4,A5,B5,C5,D5,A6,B6,C5,D6,A7,B7,C7,D7)

Is slightly shorter and simpler

Not sure if this is what you are after? :)

Answer (score 0):

Using a variant array is a quick way to avoid potentially expensive range loops

```
Sub Moved()
Dim X
Dim lngCnt As Long
Dim StrIn As String
X = Range("A1:D7")

For lngCnt = 1 To UBound(X, 1)
StrIn = StrIn & Join(Application.Index(X, lngCnt))
Next

End Sub
```